# While loop $_post from form

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include("dbFunctions.php");
$query ="SELECT * FROM `physical_examination` WHERE `PE_Opt_ans`= 0";//select form options name
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

?>

<div id="tabs-3">       
  <table>     
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" name="tab0">                                                              
  <?php while ($arrayResult = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="input"><b><?php echo      $arrayResult['PE_Opt_name']?></label></td>
         <?php  if ($arrayResult['PE_Opt_type'] == "textarea") { ?>        
            <td><textarea rows="8" cols="45"name = "other1"></textarea></td>

         <?php  } else { ?>

        <td><input type="<?php echo $arrayResult['PE_Opt_type']?>"   name="input<?php echo $arrayResult['id']?>  " ></td>
        </tr>   

      <?php  } ?>


    <?php } ?>


       <br> <input value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit1"> 

                             </form>

    </table>             

    <?php
    include "dbFunctions.php";
    if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) { 
          $number = $_POST['other1'];
```

I am stuck here.

How do I `$_POST` the form based on the while loop after I click on submit button? Do I need another `while` loop again for the name value of input `<?php echo $arrayResult['id']?>`

Comment: You can't have `<table><form>` in HTML, it should be `<form><table>`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quiet get what you want but i assume you want the contents of the textarea generated by the while loop.

Change in your loop the names from `input` to `input[]` and `other1` to `other1[]`

If you `var_dump($_POST)` afterwards you should see that they are now an array which you can loop over with `foreach`

PS: You should NEVER EVER eat raw $_POST/$_GET inputs and `PHP_SELF` is another security breach. But that's just my two cents